# Mesh is going through random and erratic deformations that only show up when rendering

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, mesh, weight-painting

There appear to be some vertices that are suddenly jumping around all over the place. The weird part is that this only happens in render and not in the viewport. It also only occurs when I'm using the cycles render engine and not eevee. The only modifiers are the armature corrective smooth.

[video of what I'm talking about](https://youtu.be/QzUL7GpF-K4)

[my blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mFwBZlEHwd4rX5D0BsdSdGLFyuMdooWD/view?usp=sharing)
[image]
[image]

Comment: would be helpful if you at least tell us one frame where it happens...

Comment: and just a hint: i would try to set correctivesmooth set to inactive to check whether it still happens then. If not - you know the reason. If yes, try to inactivate other things...